# Is there a way to center the text below inside the box?

Tags: python, text, pygame, center, box

I have a weather display on a Pi using Python and Pygame
I have 2 boxes and I am trying to display the wind speed and direction in them
this is my code

```
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (643, 67, 85, 30), 2)  # draw windspeed box 
if skyData.status == sky.STATUS_OK: 
    ren = font.render("{}°C".format(skyData.tempnow), 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(134,174,230))
else:
    ren = font.render("", 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))
screen.blit(ren, (658*HRES//1600, 84*VRES//900-ren.get_height()//2))


pg.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (872, 67, 116, 30), 2)  # draw wind direction box cardinal + Degrees
if forecastData.status == forecast.STATUS_OK:
    ren = font.render("{} {}°".format(forecastData.wind_direction_cardinal, forecastData.wind_direction), 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(134,174,230))
else:
    ren = font.render("", 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(134,174,230))
screen.blit(ren, (882*HRES//1600, 84*VRES//900-ren.get_height()//2))
```

Works beautifully but the text is never centered
If the windspeed is below 10mph the text is to the right and if the direction is N instead of NW or NNW the text is to the left

I'd like the text to center inside the specified boxes
is that possible?

This is how they look at present, if the direction changes to say S then the text is completely to the left
[Box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFuhY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the bounding rectangle of the text *Surface* with [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) and set the center of the rectangle form the center of the box. Use the rectangle to `blit` the text:

```py
box = pygame.Rect(643, 67, 85, 30), 2)
pg.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), box , 2)  # draw windspeed box 

if skyData.status == sky.STATUS_OK: 
    ren = font.render("{}°C".format(skyData.tempnow), 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(134,174,230))
else:
    ren = font.render("", 1, pg.Color('black'), pg.Color(185,208,240))

ren_rect = ren.get_rect(center = box.center)
screen.blit(ren, ren_rect)
```

Note, the *dest* argument for [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) can also be a rectnagle.